# ffill fillna python

Tags: python, pandas

Есть следующий дата фрейм. Нужно заполнить пропуски впереди стоящим значением. Ранее nan были созданы с помощью

```
(np.where(data['id']=='1.','население',np.NaN))
id|group
0|население
1|nan
2|nan
...         
115|не менее 10 МВт
116|nan
117|nan
```

Желаемый output

```
|id|name|
|0|население|
|1|население|
|2|население|
|...|...|         
|115|не менее 10 МВт|
|116|не менее 10 МВт|
|117|не менее 10 МВт|
```

Делаю `data['group']=data['group'].fillna(method='ffill',inplace=True)`, на что выдает мне столбик None

Answer (score 2):

Нужно использовать что-то одно - либо присвоение результата, либо параметр `inplace=True`. Т.е. либо так (и лучше так) - без параметра `inplace`:

```py
data['group']=data['group'].fillna(method='ffill')
```

Либо так (лучше так не надо, в будущих версиях `Pandas` уберут `inplace` отовсюду, потому что он всех только путает, как и вас в данном случае) - с параметром `inplace`, но результат не присваиваем, он уже там, где нужно должен быть:

```py
data.loc[:, 'group'].fillna(method='ffill',inplace=True)
```

При указании `inplace=True` операция проводится "по месту" и возвращается `None`, который вы и присваиваете в столбец, в котором уже всё заполнено как нужно было к моменту этого присвоения.

Comment: Я же делаю то же самое , мне выдаёт None или ничего не происходит.

Comment: Нет, вы делаете не тоже самое, прочитайте внимательно свой код и мой код. И то, что я текстом написал.

Comment: у меня в df ничего не меняется Вашим способом

Comment: Хм, странно, очень странно. Предоставьте ваши данные в воспроизводимом виде. Вы первый мой код используете? Со вторым всё же могут быть проблемы, я не помню, как там лучше делать, кажется `.loc` надо, а не просто выбирать колонку, тут получается операция на срезе. А первый код точно должен работать. На всякий случай поменяю второй код на более правильный.

Comment: С ума сойти, заменила пропуски не методом np.nan а pd.NA и все сработало

Comment: Хм, не должно быть разницы, но ок, раз работает, то хорошо